# How to select a row by index and set onclick on his first children

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
var t = $('#datatable').DataTable();
   var rtn =t.row.add( [
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer"></span>',
            con.name,
            (con.size)/1024/1024+" MB",
            con.lastmodified,
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delete" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;cursor:pointer"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil update" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor:pointer"></span>'
            ] ).draw( false );
   alert((t.row(rtn.index())).data());
  (t.row(rtn.index())).on( 'click', 'td:first-child', function () {
    /* set clickable row */
     fun(con.href);

  } );

  (t.row(rtn.index())).on( 'click', 'td:nth-child(2)', function () {
    /* set clickable row */
     fun(con.href);

  } );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Come on. Give some context at least. We can help, but we won't write code for you.

Comment: That's alright i'v found the answer ,i'm sorry but i can't express my self because i speak frensh and arabic i'm not very good in english in order to give you the maximum details of my problem